# Not able to use Apache HttpClient

Tags: android, httpclient

I want to include Apache HttpClient 4.1 to my project.

So, I added to my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ..
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.1'
}
```

Running the  the sanity test:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            EntityUtils.consume(null);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

gives the Error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method consume(Lorg/apache/http/HttpEntity;)V in class Lorg/apache/http/util/EntityUtils; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)

So why is Android calling org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar, instead of calling the added Apache HttpClient 4.1 library? And how could I force to call it?

Comment: Any solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client.

Read more details here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-apache-http-client

If you are set on using 4.1 instead of latest version try adding this dependency:

```
 compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.1.3'
```

After you build, you may want to restart your Android Studio just to make sure its not some strange glitch.

Comment: I know but somehow Android is connecting all the org.apache calls to the not existing Appache client. Its weird! But I tried what you said, added the dependency you suggested and did a "Invalidate Caches & Restart" of Android Studio and also a Clean Project. But sill the error remains.

Answer (score 1):

Try add to your `build.gradle`

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Comment: This would activate org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar which includes an Apache HttpClient but not the HttpClient version I would like to have. E.g. the method EntityUtils.consume() is not available in this version.